# Hide particular tag from product page in Woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce, tags, product

does anyone know how to hide one specific tag name from the tags list in WooCommerce Product page?

Example: in a product page i see TAGS: 1, 2, 3. I do not want to show tag 2 in tag list on every product page the tag 2 appears. Only 1 and 3.

Thanks for yours help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_the_terms` filter hook. try the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function remove_tags_links( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ){

    if( is_admin() ) return;

    // onlu apply for product_tag.
    if( $taxonomy == 'product_tag' ){

        $slugs_to_hide = array( 'test-2' ); // degine slug of tags you want to hide.
        $new_terms     = array(); // store only showing terms

        if( !empty( $terms ) ){
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                if( !in_array( $term->slug, $slugs_to_hide ) ){
                    $new_terms[$key] = $term;
                }
            }
        }

        return $new_terms;
    }

    return $terms;

}
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'remove_tags_links', 10, 3 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given is working fine.
But if you want the tags to show in the Products list on the dashboard (/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product) then you need to change :

```
if( is_admin() ) return;
```

To :

```
if( is_admin() ) return $terms;
```

Full code :

```
function remove_tags_links( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy ){

    if( is_admin() ) return $terms;
    
    // only apply for product_tag.
    if( $taxonomy == 'product_tag' ){

        $slugs_to_hide = array( 'test-2' ); // degine slug of tags you want to hide.
        $new_terms     = array(); // store only showing terms

        if( !empty( $terms ) ){
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                if( !in_array( $term->slug, $slugs_to_hide ) ){
                    $new_terms[$key] = $term;
                }
            }
        }

        return $new_terms;
    }

    return $terms;

}
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'remove_tags_links', 10, 3 );
```